# Using powershell function Send-MailMessage getting an error: Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential"

Tags: powershell, smtp, powershell-cmdlet

I want to send an email via powershell using function Send-MailMessage.

My smtp server requires UserName and Password.

I am passing it as parameters, however getting an error.

```
 $CredUser = "123UserPass"
 $CredPassword = "1234/5678/999"
 $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $CredUser, $CredPassword
 Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.amazonaws.com" -Port 587 -Credential $Credential -UseSsl -From 'DBATeam@email.com' -To 'me@email.com' -Subject 'TEST'
```

Error message:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At line:3 char:16
+ ... redential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCrede ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Send-MailMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName
At line:4 char:90
+ ... tp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" -Port 587 -Credential $Credential -UseSsl ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

I tried to use `ConvertTo-SecureString -String "mypassword"` but also getting a conversion error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$credpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "mypassword" -Force
```

Provided you are using version 5.1 or later you can also use the `::new()` static method in place o f `New-Object` (totally optional).

```
$credpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "mypassword" -Force
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new( $CredUser, $CredPassword )
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.amazonaws.com" -Port 587 -Credential $Credential -UseSsl -From 'DBATeam@email.com' -To 'me@email.com' -Subject 'TEST'
```

You can incorporate splatting if you want to add some readability:

```
$credpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "mypassword" -Force
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new( $CredUser, $CredPassword )

$SMTPParams = @{
   SmtpServer = 'smtp.amazonaws.com'
   Port       = 587
   Credential = $Credential
   UseSsl     = $true
   From       = 'DBATeam@email.com'
   To         = 'me@email.com'
   Subject    = 'TEST'
}

Send-MailMessage @SMTPParams
```

Note: some may frown on a password being visible.  You can store the password securely in a file, then call it back for use.  As long as it's by the same user on the same machine.

$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$SecurePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\temp\SecurePasswword.txt

```
$CredPassword = Get-Content C:\temp\SecurePasswword.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new( $CredUser, $CredPassword )
```

Obviously you'll want to change the path to the file, so as not to advertise it.  Establish the password file with the first 2 lines. Then use the second 2 in your current script to set up the creds for your SMTP command...

Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-5.1#example-2--create-a-secure-string-from-an-encrypted-string-in-a-file)